# There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Появилась проблема в проекте после добавления авторизации и пользователя (`Spring Security`). С авторизацией все отлично работает, но когда пытаюсь добавить новый тур как пользователь вылетает ошибка 403, до добавления пользователя работало все отлично.

Вот страница html с добавлением:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>GEOGRAPHIYAPUTESHESTVIY</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>GEOGRAPHIYAPUTESHESTVIY</h1><hr>
<#if user.email??>
    <h3>Имя компании перевозчика: <i>${user.name}</i></h3>
    <form action="/logout" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="${_csrf.token}">
        <input type="submit" value="Выйти"/>
    </form>
<#else>
    <a href="/login">Войти</a></h1>
</#if>
<hr>
<form action="/logout" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="${_csrf.token}">
    <input type="submit" value="Выйти"/>
</form>
<h4>Все возможные туры:</h4>
<form action="/" method="get">
    Поиск по названию тура: <input type="text" name="title">
    <input type="submit" value="Поиск"/>
</form>
<#list products as product>
    <div>
        <p><b>${product.title}</b> ${product.price} бел.руб. | <a href="/product/${product.id}">Подробнее...</a></p>
    </div>
<#else>
    <h3>Туров нет</h3>
</#list>
<#if user.email??>
    <hr>
    <h3>Добавить новый тур</h3>
    <form action="/product/create" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Название тура: <input type="text" name="title"/><br><br>
        Описание тура: <input type="text" name="description"/><br><br>
        Стоимость: <input type="number" name="price"/><br><br>
        Город: <input type="text" name="city"/><br><br>
        Первая фотография: <input type="file" name="file1"/><br><br>
        Вторая фотография: <input type="file" name="file2"/><br><br>
        Третья фотография: <input type="file" name="file3"/><br><br>
        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="${_csrf.token}">
        <input type="submit" value="Добавить тур"/>
    </form>
</#if>
</body>
</html>
```

Конфиг `SecurityConfig.java`:

```java
import com.example.tourism.services.CustomUserDetailsService;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

import java.util.Collection;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {
    private final CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    protected SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                        .requestMatchers(("/"), "/registration").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/product/**", "/image/**")
                        .hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN","ROLE_USER")
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin((form) -> form
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .permitAll()
                )
                .logout((logout) -> logout.permitAll());

                return http.build();
    } 

 @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(8);
    }
}
```

`ProductService.java`:

```java
import com.example.tourism.models.Image;
import com.example.tourism.models.Product;
import com.example.tourism.models.User;
import com.example.tourism.repositories.ProductRepository;
import com.example.tourism.repositories.UserRepository;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.Principal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Service
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ProductService {
private final ProductRepository productRepository;
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public List<Product> listProducts(String title) {
        if (title != null) return productRepository.findByTitle(title);
        return productRepository.findAll();
    }

    public void saveProduct(Principal principal, Product product, MultipartFile file1, MultipartFile file2, MultipartFile file3) throws IOException {
        product.setUser(getUserByPrincipal(principal));
        Image image1;
        Image image2;
        Image image3;
        if (file1.getSize() != 0) {
            image1 = toImageEntity(file1);
            image1.setPreviewImage(true);
            product.addImageToProduct(image1);
        }
        if (file2.getSize() != 0) {
            image2 = toImageEntity(file2);
            product.addImageToProduct(image2);
        }
        if (file3.getSize() != 0) {
            image3 = toImageEntity(file3);
            product.addImageToProduct(image3);
        }
        log.info("Saving new Product. Title: {}; Author email: {}", product.getTitle(), product.getUser().getEmail());
        Product productFromDb = productRepository.save(product);
        productFromDb.setPreviewImageId(productFromDb.getImages().get(0).getId());
        productRepository.save(product);
    }

    public User getUserByPrincipal(Principal principal) {
        if (principal == null) return new User();
        return userRepository.findByEmail(principal.getName());
    }

    private Image toImageEntity(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        Image image = new Image();
        image.setName(file.getName());
        image.setOriginalFileName(file.getOriginalFilename());
        image.setContentType(file.getContentType());
        image.setSize(file.getSize());
        image.setBytes(file.getBytes());
        return image;
    }

    public void deleteProduct(Long id) {
        productRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

    public Product getProductById(Long id) {
        return productRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
    }
}
```

И контроллер `ProductController.java`:

```java
import com.example.tourism.models.Product;
import com.example.tourism.services.ProductService;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.Principal;

@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ProductController {
    private final ProductService productService;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String products(@RequestParam(name = "title", required = false) String title, Principal principal, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("products", productService.listProducts(title));
        model.addAttribute("user", productService.getUserByPrincipal(principal));
        return "products";
    }

    @GetMapping("/product/{id}")
    public String productInfo(@PathVariable Long id, Model model) {
        Product product = productService.getProductById(id);
        model.addAttribute("product", product);
        model.addAttribute("images", product.getImages());
        return "product-info";
    }

    @PostMapping("/product/create")
    public String createProduct(@RequestParam("file1") MultipartFile file1, @RequestParam("file2") MultipartFile file2,
                                @RequestParam("file3") MultipartFile file3, Product product, Principal principal) throws IOException {
        productService.saveProduct(principal, product, file1, file2, file3);
        return "redirect:/";
    }

    @PostMapping("/product/delete/{id}")
    public String deleteProduct(@PathVariable Long id){
        productService.deleteProduct(id);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```xml
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
 <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

`User.java`:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Data
public class User implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "email", unique = true)
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "phone_number")
    private String phoneNumber;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "active")
    private boolean active;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "image_id")
    private Image avatar;
    @Column(name = "password", length = 1000)
    private String password;
    @ElementCollection(targetClass = Role.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "user_role",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "user")
    private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
    private LocalDateTime dateOfCreated;

    @PrePersist
    private void init() {
        dateOfCreated = LocalDateTime.now();
    }

    // security

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return roles;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return email;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return active;
    }
}
```

Enum Role.java

```java
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;

public enum Role implements GrantedAuthority {
    ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN;

    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо. pom увидел. на его основе соберу тестовый стенд, проверю ответ, дополню и отпишусь вам

Comment: Хорошо бы сущность авторизации увидеть, конечно, но вдруг поможет замена .hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN","ROLE_USER") на .hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")

Comment: Добавил User.java, замена не помогла(

Comment: А можно ещё сам инам Role показать? И точно ли в базу роли юзерам сохраняются? Таблицы проверяли через админку?

Comment: Админку я еще не добавлял потому что эту проблему не решил, а в базу юзеры прекрасно добавляются и роли сохраняются. Enum сейчас добавлю

Comment: @Override
 public String getAuthority() {
  return **name()**;
 }

Answer (score 2):

Вы сами запретили доступ к данным страницам

```java
.requestMatchers("/product/**", "/image/**")
   .hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN","ROLE_USER")
   .anyRequest().authenticated()
```

В вышеуказанном коде вы выбираете все запросы, соответствующие указанным паттернам и устанавливаете правило, которое требует, чтобы все данные запросы были авторизованы (`authenticated()`) и доступ к данным страницам могут получить только пользователи с ролями `USER` и `ADMIN` (`hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN","ROLE_USER")`)

Вы можете перенести эти запросы в предыдущее правило, которое разрешает доступ к страницам без авторизации (`.permitAll()`)

```java
requestMatchers(
   "/", 
   "/registration", 
   "/product/**", 
   "/image/**" 
).permitAll()
```

Итого

```java
import com.example.tourism.services.CustomUserDetailsService;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

import java.util.Collection;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {
    private final CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    protected SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                        .requestMatchers("/", "/registration", "/product/**", "/image/**" ).permitAll()

                )
                .formLogin((form) -> form
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .permitAll()
                )
                .logout((logout) -> logout.permitAll());

                return http.build();
    } 

 @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(8);
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```xml
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
 <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но если я так делаю, то у меня вылетает. Доступ к localhost запрещен. У вас нет прав для просмотра этой страницы. HTTP ERROR 403.

Comment: @DeLaPablo, я ответ с мобильного писал. Через 2 часа буду за компом - проверю и отпишусь

Comment: Буду ждать! Спасибо за помощь

Comment: @DeLaPablo, извиняюсь, что заставил ждать. С ходу у меня не получилось поднять тестовый стенд, а потом увлекся работой.

Comment: @DeLaPablo,  уточните пожалуйста версию спринга или лучше прикрепите pom.xml

Comment: Прикрепил pom.xml файл